# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable when calling pip in CMD

Tags: python, cmd, pip

Just installed Python.

When I call `pip` in `Cmd` this error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

why?

Comment: How did you install python? As administrator? In which cmd are you, admin?

Comment: nope not as administrator, and using as administrator

Comment: Try the good all fashion restart

Comment: Try reinstalling python to the default folder, not the `C:\Program Files`.

Comment: its working now, but when i try installing something..` SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` shows up..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20TypeError%3a%20%27module%27%20object%20is%20not%20callable

Comment: *SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED* That's a different problem and should be asked in a separate question.